# Change the appearance of only one ListView items

Tags: java, android

In my ListView, I want the first item to have a special style, while the other items have the regular layout called by the adapter:

```
    myAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list);

    // Set Appearance of item 1 here
    //

    myListView.setAdapter(myAdapt);
```

Is there a way to do that? The item cannot be added via a TextView using the `addHeaderView` method because I might have to delete it at some point, which the adapter will not let me do (if there's actually a way to do that, shoot!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best place where you can customize this is extending an `ArrayAdapter` and doing so in the `getView()` method.

This way, you get the layout in the second parameter (usually called `convertView`, but not necessarily) - basically the row's layout, and the first one (called usually `position`), references to the current position of the current row. You could do something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
  ...

  if (position == 0)
    convertView.setBackground(R.id.first_row);
  else
    convertView.setBackground(R.id.any_other_row);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Was about to write the same answer. However I thought the first element has position 0 ?

Comment: Don't forget that he also need to remove that item later

Comment: @nKn Hey, I tried your method with two ids: one I defined myself for the first row, `R.id.hintText`, one predefined by android, `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked`. I get an error, which is not sup rinsing since setBackground needs a Drawable as an input. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can use `setBackgroundResource(int resid)` from `View` for that. You might want to have a see at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do is to create your Custom adapter that will support different item types. Than you can do whatever you want with your items : add or remove them from list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`